# Assigning array to multidimensional array and vice verse

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a M-by-N multidimensional array and a M-times-N size one dimensional array then if M = N.

```
for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        arr2d[i][j] = arrd1d[i * M + j];
    }
}
```

Seems to work, but I can't figure something out for the general case.

Comment: Have you tried changing `i*M` to `i*N`?

Comment: The only difference would be that it would be assign in row order instead of column order.

Comment: How have you declared the two arrays?

Comment: what is the sample input for 1d array and the expected output?

Comment: The maximum index you are trying to extract from the 1d array is (M-1)M + N-1 = M^2-M+N-1 which exceeds its length which is MN. If you change iM to iN then the max index is (M-1)N+N-1=NM-1 which is exactly right. Have you tried changing iM to iN?

Comment: You're right. iN does work. Could have sworn that I had tried it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so we can have an official answer, you are trying to access an element from the 1d array past its range. Changing `i*M` to `i*N` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
arr2d[i][j] = arrd1d[i * M + j];
```

to

```
arr2d[i][j] = arrd1d[i * N + j];
```